# Remove external file from postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I added a file to postgres using `\i /path/to/some/file.sql` but there was a typo in the file.

Here's what I had in the file:

```
CREATE VIEW holidays AS
  SELECT event_id AS holiday_id, title AS name, starts AS date
  FROM events
  WHERE title LIKE '%Day%' AND venue_id IS NULL;
```

In the original version I had `%DAY%`.  When running `\i /path/to/some/file.sql` again, I receive this error:

```
ERROR:  relation "holidays" already exists
```

How do I undo this relation to get the code to run again?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The \i command does not "add a file" that can later be removed. It simply runs the SQL within the file, as if you had typed it at the psql command prompt. If you want to undo what you did, it will depend on what exactly the SQL was.

Comment: I've updated my question... Actually, I figured it out from what you said and just ran `DROP VIEW holidays`